# Rabbitmq spring java configuration with apache RouteBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I want to configure spring boot application with rabbitmq and apache RouteBuilder, can any one suggest me how to do that

Answer (score 3):

Do you mention Apache camel [RouteBuiler](http://camel.apache.org/routebuilder.html)?
If you say yes, you can use [RabbitMQ component](http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html) that provided by Apache camel since version 2.12.
For more detail, please check my sample code:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->

@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
    // listen from exchange and log to console
        from("rabbitmq:topic_logs2?" +
            "vhost=myvhost&hostname=localhost&portNumber=5672" +
            "&username=myname&password=mypassword" +
            "&exchangeType=topic&autoDelete=false&queue=my_queue&routingKey=test.log")
        .log("From RabbitMQ: ${body}");
    }
}
```